# Select data out sqlDB by currentDate

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How can I select from the database only the tasks from the current day. I have already an variable with the name currentDate. Therein I can store the current day. 
I've already tried by selectArgs doing this > `"SELECT WHERE" + TaskContract.Columns.DATE + " == " currentDate`

```
Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID,TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null, null, null, null, TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");
```

Comment: In your selection don't you want to compare to the time not the task (assuming task is the name of the task)? Also what is the type of the `TIME` column and the `currentDate` variable?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I'm sorry I meant that I tried `TaskContract.Columns.DATE` instead of `TaskContract.Columns.TASK`

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan the type of the DATE is a string and the type of currentDate is also a string

Comment: I'm assuming the format of the currentDate String matches the format of the String saved in the database correct?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan yes that's right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID,TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            TaskContract.Columns.DATE + " = ?",
            new String[] {currentDate},
            null,
            null,
            TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");
```

Comment: It was hard to format and get the parameters correct. Can you try once more? I made an edit that isn't listed. If it still doesn't work I need the error.

Comment: That at least means what I gave you successfully ran. Some reasons it would show nothing is if you aren't handling the results from the cursor, the `currentDate` String does not match the `TaskContract.Columns.DATE` text format, or you do not have any entries for the specified date. Can you check those?